# Copy only changes made to main database to database on device

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am attempting to work on an app where a version of the main database will be stored on the device. However this database would need to be updated with changes made in the main database. 
Because of the size that this database may be, I would like to look at other options apart from updating the entire database.

So, is there a way that I can update the database on the devices with only the changes that has been made on the main database since their last update?

Thank you

Comment: Is the database being changed on the device?

Comment: @CL. Once the data is placed on the device, it has to mirror/ download the changes made on the main sql database

Answer (score 0):

add a timestamp in every record and store somewhere the last timestamp that an update/addition occured. Do the same in the devices and do something like this:

```
If Device.Timestamp<Online.Timestamp then
get recorded that happen after Device.Timestamp
```

(Use a way to record the time that is exacly the same for device and online database like taking the current time from the online server)

Comment: This does not handle deletions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternate ways of determining what has changed since the last update:

1. On the server database, create a log of all changes (insertions/updates/deletions), together with a timestamp. (For insertions and updates, an additional timestamp column in each table would suffice, but at least deletions have to be recorded separately.)

   The device records the last timestamp when it does a download.
   When doing the next download, it tells the server to give it only rows/changes with a larger timestamp.

   (The timestamp does not need to be an actual timestamp; it just needs to be monotonically increasing.)
2. When downloading, the server creates a copy of the database, so that there is one copy with the current state of each device.
   When doing the next download, the server compares that copy with the live database, and sends only what has changed.

Typically, the first alternative is used, because it needs less storage on the server. However, it requires that the server database (and probably all programs accessing it) must be changed to correctly manage the log.

Comment: I am interested in the second method beause as you said, the program will have to be modified. 
But I am not sure how the server on the device will compare with the live database and then execute the commands (insert/update etc) to make them current
Can you provide a link that better explains this

Comment: To get new/changed rows, execute `SELECT * FROM Live.Table EXCEPT SELECT * FROM Device.Table`; to get deleted rows, execute `SELECT ID FROM Device.Table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Live.Table)`. The server then sends this data (for each table) to the device, which merges it.